# Spash screen with 2 options

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to find a convenience plugin for splash screens that I often see usually for websites that have 2 distinct parts separate from each other, I don't know what they're called or if they have a name.

Example: [This template here](http://remtsoy.com/tf_templates/maxshop/demo_v3_0_2/index-layout-5.html)

And I would like to make a similar design on the landing page.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Does it have to be a plugin? You could do set something up with bootstrap similar to [this](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/dRBojb) and amend the divs for your needs. And add then add the fancy scroll effects with JS.

Comment: It's not called a splash screen, there's really no name for it, just a design concept, you might confuse people what you mean by splash screen, maybe you mean landing page?

Comment: @JoeB. Thank you, I'll be sure to check that out. After examining that page I thought bootstrap is a Jquery plugin.

Comment: @Mindless According to this [page](https://instapage.com/what-is-a-splash-page-chapter-2) and a few other that I looked into, it is called a splash screen. The football.com example in there is basically what I want. I didn't know how to refer to them either, took a while to finally narrow it down to a few words.

Comment: @Ere-Eye [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/) is a framework for HTML and CSS. It does have JS extention as well.

Comment: @Ere-Eye in the page you referenced, it's called a splash page not splash screen, splash screen is different. It's bootstrap plus some more custom css and jquery involved. Easier option would be to purchase a template similar to the one you have.